# How to get processed and delivered metrics using Sendgrid API?

Tags: api, sendmail, send, sendgrid

Sendgrid's API has endpoints in place to get the list of emails back for bounces, invalid emails, unsubscribes, etc. Basically everything on the suppressions list. However, I can't seem to find a way to get the list of emails for the good emails, aka processed and delivered. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I found one, which isn't described in the documentation on SendGrid site.
I use this `email_activity?events=processed` endpoint  to get list of processed emails. According to this, the request URL should look like `https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/email_activity?events=processed&offset=0`.